# Saving through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How good is saving from model not from controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's great to do that in callbacks.

ex: you create a user who must have a profile=> you add an after_create on the User model.

I'll try to find out some more examples.

Comment: That is exactly why I need that for. I have callback function and need to save data right from the model.

Comment: Great :) Please don't forget to mark the question as solved. Cheers

Comment: please think about validating the answer.